# Tkinter in Python 3.8.5 : Having an issue creating multiple images as buttons within a function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently having an issue with tkinter/python. I'm trying to create buttons with images within a for-loop. I've done some reading on here about others having a similar issue and it was resolved by setting a global variable. The issue I am having is that when I create the grid layout for my buttons the image is only applied to the last button as the global variable is being overwritten. I'm pretty new to python/coding in general so I don't even know if I'm going about it the right way. I'd like to be able to dynamically create the buttons/images so that I can items more easily in the future without having to hard code them. Any advice is appreciated, thank you!

```
 def OnRaidMaterialClick(raidMaterial, raidConstruction):
    global imgVar
    rowCounter = 0
    columnCounter = 0  
    
    for attr, value in raidConstruction.__dict__.items():
        
        labelVar = Label(root, text = value['name'])
        imgVar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(value['image']))
        buttonVar = Button(root, text = value['name'], 
                           image = imgVar, 
                           compound = TOP).grid(row = rowCounter, column = columnCounter)
        
        if columnCounter < 3:
            columnCounter += 1
        
        if columnCounter == 3:
            columnCounter = 0
            rowCounter += 1
        
        if rowCounter == 3:
            rowCounter = 0
```

The code runs and compiles ok, I have the grid layout I'd like, but the only image that shows is the last image in the grid.

I've looked into creating dynamic variables but was told that is bad practice so I'm trying to avoid that. I've read that dictionaries are the way to go but I can't figure out how to apply that data structure to my problem and come up with a working solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the reference of the image instance to an attribute of the button:

```py
for attr, value in raidConstruction.__dict__.items():
    labelVar = Label(root, text=value['name'])
    imgVar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=value['image'])
    buttonVar = Button(root, text=value['name'], image=imgVar, compound=TOP)
    buttonVar.grid(row=rowCounter, column=columnCounter)
    buttonVar.image = imgVar  # save the image reference to an attribute of button
    ...
```

Note that `global imgVar` is not necessary and can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried what you suggested. It now creates buttons (minus the images) but overlays them over my original button. Thank you again for the reply, this one is boggling me I'm going to keep doing some more reading on tkinter. It really doesn't seem to like the fact that it's creating buttons within a method/function.

Comment: Did you update the `rowCounter` and `columnCounter` as in your original code?  My posted code is just showing the related part, you should keep the other part of the function as in your posted code.

Comment: Yes, I kept the rowCounter/columnCounter where I instantiated and in the if statements.

Comment: It was my mistake, I did not change the (image = imgVar) within the buttonVar variable from the first response. Thank you so much for your help, the beginner that I am I've been banging my head on that problem for the last day or so. Thanks again! If you don't mind me asking, could you explain briefly where I went wrong?

Comment: Your code use same global variable `imgVar` for all the images created in the for loop, so only the last image created in the for loop is finally referenced by `imgVar`.  The other images other than the last one will be garbage collected after the function exits because there is no variable referencing them.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are reassigning imgVar each iteration, which is confusing Tkinter when the master runs its main loop.

A simple way to fix this is to create a list and hold each image in there instead. For example:

```
imgVars = []
imgVars.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imagePath)))
```

You can create the list before the for loop and append the value in the for loop. Then, when you create your button, you set the parameter:

```
image = imgVars[-1]
```

so you can get the latest value in imgVars (the value you just appended).

This would be your fixed code with this solution:

```
def OnRaidMaterialClick(raidMaterial, raidConstruction):    
rowCounter = 0
columnCounter = 0
imgVars = [] # Create list which will hold images

for attr, value in raidConstruction.__dict__.items():
    
    labelVar = Label(root, text = value['name'])
    imgVars.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(value['image']))) # Append image to imgVars list
    buttonVar = Button(root, text = value['name'], 
                       image = imgVars[-1], # Set image to be latest image that was just appended
                       compound = TOP).grid(row = rowCounter, column = columnCounter)

    if columnCounter < 3:
        columnCounter += 1
    
    if columnCounter == 3:
        columnCounter = 0
        rowCounter += 1
    
    if rowCounter == 3:
        rowCounter = 0
```

You can also use dynamic variables, but I wouldn't recommend it either. Also, you talked about putting

```
global imgVar
```

in your code, but that shouldn't affect it as you are declaring it and using it in the same scope.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! I've just tried your solution but I'm still having the same issue. No images are appearing at all on the created buttons. The PhotoImage objects are being created just not displayed.

Comment: @CyclopsEyepatch Huh. May I see an input for raidConstruction? I know that someone else answered here but I am confused on why it didn't fix anything.